# How to prevent the component from being destroyed when it is referenced in multiple places?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, aura, aura-attribute

I am referencing the component instance X within multiple other components dynamically. When I remove component instance X from one of the components, it is removed everywhere. The question is: how do I remove the component instance X from one component while retaining it inside the other components.

Here is an example

**componentPlaceholder.cmp**

```
<aura:component>
    {! v.body }
</aura:component>
```

**myapp.app**

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">

        <aura:attribute name="mystr" type="String" required="false" default="hello world" access="private" description="" />
        <aura:attribute name="mycmp" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false" access="private">
            <h1><aura:text value="{! v.mystr }" /></h1>
        </aura:attribute>

        <div>MyCmp</div>
        <div>{! v.mycmp }</div>

        <div style="background: red">
            <c:componentPlaceholder aura:id="first" />
        </div>

        <div style="background: yellow">
            <c:componentPlaceholder aura:id="second" />
        </div>

        <div></div>

        <ui:button  label="Set body in both component placeholder" press="{!c.updateCmps}"/>
        <ui:button  label="Set body to empty in the second component placeholder" press="{!c.removeBodyFromSecond}"/>
</aura:application>
```

**myappController.js**

```
({
    updateCmps : function(component, event, helper) {
        var mycmp = component.get('v.mycmp');
        component.find('first').set('v.body',mycmp);
        component.find('second').set('v.body',mycmp);
    },

    removeBodyFromSecond : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.find('second').set('v.body',[]);
    }   
})
```

**Output**

1) Screen Initialisation
[image: Hello world component declared]

2) After executing Set body in both component placeholder
[image: Hello world appears in all instances]

3) After executing Set body to empty in the second component placeholder pressed
[image: All refrenced to hello world are removed]

As you can see in the sequence, the result is that the mycmp component is removed everywhere. However, I only want to remove it from the componentPlaceholder with aura:id of second.

Answer (score 2):

You need two different instances of mycmp variable so that you can decouple both the aura:component variable

```
<aura:application extends="force:slds">

<aura:attribute name="mystr" type="String" required="false" default="hello world" access="private" description="" />
 <aura:attribute name="mycmp1" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false" access="private">
        <h1><aura:text value="{! v.mystr }" /></h1>
    </aura:attribute>
 <aura:attribute name="mycmp2" type="Aura.Component[]" required="false" access="private">
        <h1><aura:text value="{! v.mystr }" /></h1>
    </aura:attribute>
<div>MyCmp</div>   
<div style="background: red">
    <c:componentPlaceholder aura:id="first" />
</div>

<div style="background: yellow">
    <c:componentPlaceholder aura:id="second" />
</div>

  <div></div>

  <ui:button label="Set body in both component placeholder" press="{!c.updateCmps}"/>
  <ui:button label="Set body to empty in the second component placeholder" press="{!c.removeBodyFromSecond}"/>
</aura:application>
```

Controller JS

```
({
  updateCmps : function(component, event, helper) {
    var mycmp = component.get('v.mycmp');
    component.find('first').set('v.body',mycmp1);
    component.find('second').set('v.body',mycmp2);
  },

   removeBodyFromSecond : function(component, event, helper) {
    component.find('second').set('v.body',[]);
   }   
})
```

Comment: This code gives me error when I try saying `myCmp` is not available. Also in the question, OP is using `myStr` attribute inside the `myCmp` attribute.

Comment: I'm sorry but it doesn't answer my question. Your example implies using different instances of the component. My intention is to use the same component instance. Also your example excludes the default value of mycmp1 and mycmp2 aura:attribute(s).

Comment: I see the error.Working on fixing it

Comment: @Artur Check the answer now .The problem is if you use only variable to bind ,then because of two way binding the view is tightly bound to the variable .Hope that helps

Comment: I see one problem with this. When you clear second component body in `removeBodyFromSecond` function, the value of the attribute `mycmp2` on the parent component is also set to empty. @MohithShrivastava Is it possible to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: Probably one could just use one way binding then i feel .Like {#v.cmp2}.I have not tried this but should work

Comment: No. It is not working. As per the documentation(https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/expr_data_binding.htm#expr_data_binding), `Objects, such as Array or Map, are passed by reference, so changes to the data in the child propagate to the parent. However, change handlers in the parent aren’t notified. The same behavior applies for changes in the parent propagating to the child.` Because `mycmp2` is of array type, it is always binded(I hope I am wrong!).

Comment: We are not modifying the component itself. In the original example, the component is removed from body by setting the body to empty array. The component itself does not get modified. After the body in second component is set to empty, the component gets destroyed. Its isValid state becomes false and that is why it disappears from everywhere. So the question is how to prevent it being destroyed.